# regular expression to match all domain names except admin / www / mail

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions, but Give me this, I need to find a match:

```
a.com
b.com
c.com
aa.com
admin.com
www.com
mail.com
vg.com
```

As a result, I have found a regular expression to all domains except the admin / www / mail.

I wrote this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+.com
```

But how to exclude admin, mail, www

I tried this:

```
^(www|mail|admin)[a-zA-Z0-9]+.com
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: That regex simply represents one or more alpha numeric characters.

Comment: Ok, i know. But how to exclude this words "www,admin,mail"

Comment: Regexes don't really exist in a vacuum. Can you show us the line of code that uses the regex? Note that your regex doesn't match `a.com`, only `a` and `com`.

Comment: Look, i edited post, maybe now it would be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\w+(?<!admin|mail|www)\.com
```

Here it is with some tests
http://www.rubular.com/r/frRl1ucR8J

Further reading on Regular Expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

And the trick I used is called Negative LookBehind http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks for help and for links. This works! Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple to exclude some things, but here is a link to help:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions.html

is it possible to use a replace first?  You could first do a find/replace to eliminate lines that match the things you want to skip, then use your regular expression.

Comment: ignore what I said, deltree has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this to search for a string that doesn't contain admin:

```
^((?!admin).)*$
```

I'm not sure how to do it for multiple strings...

Comment: Look, i edited post, maybe it would be more clear what i want

Answer (score 0):

I use this, somewhat similar to already answered.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9._'%+-]+@(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}|(?!hotmail|gmail|yahoo|live|msn|outlook|comcast|verizon)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{1,3})(\]?)$/i
```